# modify function called by check constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server, check-constraints, referential-integrity

I have some CHECK constraints that all depend on a unique user defined function. They all look like this:

```
ALTER TABLE t_adresse ADD CONSTRAINT chkAdresse_PaysCode CHECK(LibelleCodeMatch('PAYS', PaysCode)=1);
```

I need to update LibelleCodeMatch().

So I disabled all CHECK constraints:

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
```

I can query the sys.check_constraints system view to verify the constraints are in effect disabled:

```
SELECT 
 name,
 is_disabled,
 is_not_trusted,
FROM sys.check_constraints;
```

[image]

But then, when I try to DROP and re create the function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS LibelleCodeMatch;
```

I get Error Msg 3729, Level 16. Impossible to DROP FUNCTION LibelleCodeMatch because it is referenced by object chkRaisonSociale_FormeJuridiqueCode.

Is there a way to avoid dropping and re creating all constraints ?

Comment: I can think of no workaround to avoid dropping/recreating the constraints since it's a hard dependency.

Comment: which version of SQL Server are you using ??

Comment: Have you tried using `CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION` instead of `DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS` followed by `CREATE FUNCTION`?

Comment: which kind of function is LibelleCodeMatch ??

Comment: `ALTER FUNCTION` will not work if the depending objects are constraints. It works if the dependency are triggers, store procedures or other functions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Using SQL Server 2016

Comment: @RichardDeeming: I haven't try yet. I am.

Comment: LibelleCodeMatch is a scalar function.

Comment: CREATE OR ALTER: nice try, but same punishment. Error Msg 3729.

Comment: Honestly, I feel like this is just another reason why it's a bad idea to use user defined scalar functions as a `CONSTRAINT`. As has been mentioned the only way to do what you want is to drop all the constraints that use the function, alter said function, and then recreate all the constraints. Not a particularly simple task, and likely expensive when all the constraints has to be rechecked.

Comment: What does the function actually do, and can it be optimized away?